# How do you increase the font size of Outlook 2003?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

The font is super tiny, and I could have sworn that Ctrl+mouse wheel changed the font size.  It does that for regular websites, but for some reason it isn't working when I try to do it now, so I am stuck with the super small font and my neck is straining to see my emails... :(  There also doesn't seem to be anything in the Tools->Options->Mail Format..

Any suggestions?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some surfing and I ran across this page:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/21b15095-7496-47d7-a04e-5ad241e21f33/

Scroll to the bottom and it has a good list of suggestions for what part of outlook you want the font size to increase at.

In case you have a large number of applications with too small of a font, you might try reducing your screen resolution. It's not an Office fix, but could be contributing to your problem.